# xcodebuild crashes on start

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, xcodebuild

At some point I have noticed `xcodebuild` stopped working. Example:

```
xtmq@xtmqmac ~ % xcodebuild --help
2021-03-09 17:13:07.961 xcodebuild[8574:125230] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-17707/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/Foundation/Specifications/XCSpecification.m:1521
Details:  propertyList should be an instance inheriting from TSPropertyListDictionary, but it is nil
Object:   <XCSpecificationProxy: 0x7ffd76f94630>
Method:   -loadedSpecification
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ffd75519810>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   -[XCSpecificationProxy loadedSpecification] (in DevToolsCore)
  4   +[XCSpecification specificationForIdentifier:inDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5   +[PBXTarget buildSystemDefaultMacros] (in DevToolsCore)
  6   XCInitializeCoreIfNeeded (in DevToolsCore)
  7   +[Xcode3CoreInitializer ide_initializeWithOptions:error:] (in Xcode3Core)
  8   _IDEInitializeBuildSystem (in IDEFoundation)
  9   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
 10   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 11   main (in xcodebuild)
 12   start (in libdyld.dylib)
zsh: abort      xcodebuild --help
```

Interesting things:

- there is no directory `/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs`
- xcode itself works fine at the same time

I have tried to reinstall xcode command line tools, no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove and install xcode again from scratch fixed the issue finally.